# Cleaner way to get HABTM value with associated Model using CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have the following setup:

Model: User

Model: Client

User hasAndBelongsToMany Client

Client hasAndBelongsToMany User

DB Tables:

Users

- id
- lots of fields

Clients

- id
- lots of fields

Cliens_Users

- id
- client_id
- user_id
- status

Everything is working just peachy but I am wondering if there is a better way to get the status field (associated with the HABTM table) with my Client model.

Here is what I'm doing:

ClientsController.php

```
public function view($id = null) {
    $this->Client->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Client->exists()) {
      throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid client'));
    }

    $this->Client->contain('User.id');
    $this->Client = $this->Client->read(null, $id);
    $this->set('client', $this->Client);

}
```

the var_dump on my $this->Client looks like this:

```
array
  'Client' => 
    array
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'first_name' => string 'Matt' (length=4)
      'last_name' => string 'Moses' (length=4)
      'address_1' => string '123 S Happy Lane' (length=16)
      'address_2' => string '' (length=0)
      'city' => string 'Yourtown' (length=5)
      'state' => string 'TX' (length=2)
      'zip' => string '12345' (length=5)
      'phone_home' => string '8014567899' (length=10)
      'phone_work' => string '8014567899' (length=10)
      'phone_cell' => string '8014567899' (length=10)
      'email' => string 'matt@matt.com' (length=13)
      'created' => string '2012-06-13 04:41:19' (length=19)
      'modified' => string '2012-06-13 04:41:19' (length=19)
'User' => 
  array
    0 => 
      array
        'id' => string '1' (length=1)
        'ClientsUser' => 
          array
            ...
```

Clients/view.ctp

```
...
<?php echo $client['User'][0]['ClientsUser']['status']; ?>
...
```

To me this last line screams "there is a cleaner way" but I can't seem to find anything on the matter. Any thoughts?

Comment: `$this->Client = $this->Client->read(null, $id);` you do realize you are setting the Client model now to an array, right?

Comment: I didn't realize that. Could you explain? I'm still pretty new to Cake.

Comment: `$this->Client` is the model instance, you're now assigning that variable an array so you will no longer be able to use the model to  do find() calls and etc. Create a new var, `$client = $this->Client->find(...)` then `$this->set('client', $client);` or shorter `$this->set(compact('client'));`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. My original question is still open for discussion. It seems untidy to step down through so many arrays in the view. Is there a better way to associate that 'status' field more directly with the Client model?

Comment: Only to confirm: One Client can have different (N) Active Users, while 1 User can have different (N amount) clients as well? Are you sure you need a HABTM for this relationship?